# Using react-native-ble-plx in Expo, creating a new BleManager gets me: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient')"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-ble-plx, react-native-ble-manager

I'm using the react-native-ble-plx library for a React Native project in Expo, but every time get the same [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a7Jb.png).

I've written my own app, and I've also cloned projects on GitHub that use `react-native-ble-plx`, but I always get this same exact error: BleManager cannot be instantiated.

I'm running the project with `npx expo start` or `npx expo start --web`.

The answers on [React Native TypeError: Cannot read property 'createClient' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294985/react-native-typeerror-cannot-read-property-createclient-of-undefined) were ineffective.

Does anyone know how to get over this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use native modules with Expo Go.
you should build a custom dev client with this comman:
--- eas build -p android --profile development --local